# Understanding Various I/O systems java

Tags: java, io, bufferedstream

i have been reading through the java tutorials on oracle.com recently and i am trying to understand I/O. But there are so many things, a lot of which appear to be the same, such as:
Data streams
Scanner
printwriter
buffered streams
file i/o streams
filtered streams
etc.

specifically, for example, what is the difference between a scanner and a data stream?

at first i could keep on top of it all but there were just too many streams and i/os. does anyone know of a good tutorial or website that could get all of this clear. my lack of understanding is starting to get annoying.

Comment: It's really very simple. An `(Input|Output)Stream` is a stream of bytes from somewhere. A `Reader|Writer` is a stream of characters also from somewhere. Everything else is a decorator pattern (buffering etc). A `Scanner` is a character stream tokeniser. P.S don't forget `Channel`s and `RamdomAccessFiles`s.

Answer (score 1):

A `Scanner` can be *attached to* a `File`, `Stream`, or `String`, `Readable`, or anything that derives from those classes. Think of it like a consumer. It eats things when you ask it to.

A `Stream` is a source. Some input streams have a signal that says "I'm out of input!" If you continue to consume a stream that is already out of input, Java usually waits for more input or simply throws an exception. It is important to note that once a stream is consumed, it is gone forever. Some readers have mechanisms that will "reset" a stream to an earlier point, but these fancy schmancy mechanisms are not part of a standard stream. Think of them like rivers. Once you let part of the river flow by, it's gone.

`System.in` is one example of an `InputStream` that is, by default, hooked to the console. Imagine it is feeding straight from your keyboard. You can attach a Scanner to it and attempt to consume input from the user. Scanner can capture things that you type, but if you don't store it in a variable, your keyboard isn't going to type itself again.

Answer (score 1):

This is a tough question to answer. I know previous when I was learning network programming I had the same confusion.
You could take a look at Lars Vogel's tutorials - he writes good code that make things easy to understand: http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/JavaIO/article.html

Also if you have a good book, the Java classes may make more sense after you get familiar with them. Elliot "Rusty" Harold makes a good Java Network programming book:
[Java Network Programming](http://shop.oreilly.com/product/0636920028420.do)

You need to get familiar with the "java.io.*" classes and what each one might be used for. There is a reason why there are so many, since you would use one particular class for one type of application.